# Android Dialog Box without buttons

Tags: android

Can i create a dialog box without negative or positive buttons. That destroys it self after specific action?

```
 AlertDialog.Builder dialog_detect= new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
 dialog.setTitle("Detecting.....");
 dialog.setMessage("Please Wait");
 dialog.show();
```

Comment: build your own custom dialog and call `dismiss()` method when you want. reference:http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2012/05/using-dialogfragments.html

Comment: You can try custom dialog from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17994238/android-dialog-box-without-buttons/17994633#17994633)

Comment: You can create a custom dialog: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13341560/how-to-create-a-custom-dialog-box-in-android.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can do this very easily.

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

// set title
alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Your Title");

// set dialog message
alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Message here!").setCancelable(false);

// create alert dialog
AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

// show it
alertDialog.show();

// After some action
alertDialog.dismiss();
```

If you have a reference to the `AlertDialog` somewhere else, you can still call `alertDialog.dismiss()`.  This closes the dialog.

Comment: 08-01 14:45:20.422: E/AndroidRuntime(10831): java.lang.NullPointerException
 IT returns this error

Comment: You're going to need to post some code for me to see what's going on

Comment: At least on newer versions of Android this results in a dialog with a OK button.

Answer (score 4):

Really depends on what "action" is being performed:

---

```
 AlertDialog.Builder dialog_detect= new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
 dialog.setTitle("Detecting.....");
 dialog.setMessage("Please Wait");
 dialog.show();

 timeConsumingDetectMethod();

 dialog.dismiss();
```

This way you get a frozen UI until `timeConsumingDetectMethod()` finishes.

---

However, the following way runs the action in background, while a very responsive dialog is shown. Also, cancels the action when dialog is cancelled.

```
AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> task = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

        private AlertDialog dialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            dialog= new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            dialog.setTitle("Detecting.....");
            dialog.setMessage("Please Wait");

            dialog.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
                    cancel(true);
                }
            });

            dialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            timeConsumingDetectMethod();
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            dialog.dismiss();
        }

    }.execute();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try Custom Dialog design u r on Dialog and use it as u wish to use them

```
final Dialog dialog= new Dialog(context);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.pre_confirmation_dailog); 
dialog.setTitle("Details...");
dialog.show();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also write crocboy's code like this:

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context)    
    .setTitle("Your Title")
    .setMessage("Message here!")
    .setCancelable(false)
    .create();

alertDialog.show();

// After some action
alertDialog.dismiss();
```

It does exactly the same thing, it's just more compact.

Answer (score 2):

You can call `alertDialog .dismiss ()` after any action.

Comment: that craches the program

Comment: define to global veriable for alertDialog and check if(alertDialog != null)

Answer (score 1):

to show dialog:-

```
ProgressDialog pd = ProgressDialog.show(context,"TITLE","MSG");
```

to dismiss

```
pd.dismiss();
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement a timer and set it to dismiss the DialogBox after a few seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You can try custom dialog as you like

```
Dialog dialog_help = new Dialog(this);
dialog_help.setContentView(R.layout.title_multi_selectitems_dialog);
EditText et_1 = (EditText) dialog_help.findViewById(R.id.et_help_1);
dialog_help.setCancelable(true);
dialog_help.setTitle("   Help   ");
dialog_help.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
dialog_help.show();
dialog_help.getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
dialog_help.getWindow().setLayout(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct code of [crocboy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17994317/1590950) is this:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

// set title
builder.setTitle("Your Title");

// set dialog message
builder.setMessage("Message here!").setCancelable(false);

// create alert dialog
AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();

// show it
alertDialog.show();

// After some action
alertDialog.dismiss();
```